# WCF - Login/Logout of chat service causing issues

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF service hosted in a windows service and I am having issues with client login and log out.

In the client side code Login I sometimes get the following exception.

`Exception thrown: System.ServiceModel.FaultException 1 in System.ServiceModel.dll`

`Additional information: The operation 'RefreshClients' could not be completed because the sessionful channel timed out waiting to receive a message.  To increase the timeout, either set the receiveTimeout property on the binding in your configuration file, or set the ReceiveTimeout property on the Binding directly.`

I have recievedTimeout like so `receiveTimeout="00:00:30"`, in the binding. But the above exception is almost instant. Now I am no expert but that says to me it has 30 seconds before a timeout occurs yet my exception happens almost instantly.

Client side code - Login

```
private DuplexChannelFactory<IMessageComs> remoteFactory;
private IMessageComs remoteProxy;
private Client clientUser;

public bool Login()
        {
            ConnectionStatus = "Logging in";

            IsConnecting = true;

            try
            {
                var ctx = new InstanceContext(CallBacks);
                remoteFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMessageComs>(ctx, "NetTcpBinding_IMessageComs");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ConnectionStatus = "Remote Factory Error";
                IsConnecting = false;
                return false;
            }

            remoteFactory.Closed += remoteFactory_Closed;
            remoteFactory.Opening += remoteFactory_Opening;
            CallBacks.ClientsChanged += CallBacks_ClientsChanged;

            try
            {
                remoteProxy = remoteFactory.CreateChannel();                 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ConnectionStatus = "Remote Proxy Error";
                IsConnecting = false;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                clientUser = remoteProxy.ClientConnect(Environment.UserName.ToUpper()); << Exception Happens Here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                IsConnecting = false;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }

            if (clientUser != null)
            {
                ConnectionStatus = "Online";
                IsConnecting = false;
                LoggedIn = true;
                remoteFactory.Faulted += remoteFactory_Faulted;

                // Now get the online user list
                var users = remoteProxy.GetClientsAsync();

                var connectedUser = users.Result;

                if (connectedUser != null)
                {
                    foreach (Client c in connectedUser)
                        OnlineUsers.Add(c);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                IsConnecting = false;
                ConnectionStatus = "Offline";
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

ServerSide Code

```
public Client ClientConnect(string userName)
    {
        AddEvent(userName + " is attempting to connect");

        var exists = Clients.Where(x => x.Client.UserName == userName);

        if (exists.Count() == 0)
        {
            Client c = new Client();
            c.UserName = userName;
            var tmpNo = c.ID;   // Force ID generation?
            c.SessionID = OperationContext.Current.Channel.SessionId;

            ServerClient sc = new ServerClient(c, CurrentCallback);

            OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += Channel_Faulted;

            Clients.Add(sc);

            AddEvent(userName + " now connected and clients being notified");

            if (Clients.Count > 0)
            {
                // Get clients list
                var Clientlist = new List<Client>();

                foreach (ServerClient s in Clients)
                {
                    Clientlist.Add(s.Client);
                }

                foreach (ServerClient s in Clients)
                {
                    s.CallBack.RefreshClients(Clientlist);
                }
            }               

            return c;
        }
        else
        {
            AddEvent(userName + " is already connected");
            return exists.First().Client;
        }
    }
```

EDIT 1: Stack trace

```
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
```

Exception Detail Stack Trace - Server stack trace:

```
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfIdleAborted(ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at EMS.Messaging.Service.IMessageComsCallBack.RefreshClients(List`1 clients)
   at EMS.Messaging.Service.ComsService.ClientConnect(String userName)
   at SyncInvokeClientConnect(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Edit 2: Server Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="EMS.Messaging.Service.ComsService" behaviorConfiguration="MessagingServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="EMS.Messaging.Service.IMessageComs" bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://SERVERNAME:8000/MessagingService/service" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://SERVERNAME:8001/MessagingService/service" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MessagingServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpBinding" maxBufferSize="67108864" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" maxBufferPoolSize="67108864" transferMode="Buffered" closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                         openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxConnections="100" portSharingEnabled="true">
          <security mode="None"/>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="67108864" maxBytesPerRead="67108864" maxStringContentLength="67108864" />
          <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="mexBinding">
          <tcpTransport maxPendingConnections="100">
            <connectionPoolSettings groupName="default" maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint="100"/>
          </tcpTransport>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your timeout is set at client or server side? You must set in both.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace from the exception?

Comment: @RicardoPontual timeout is set on both

Comment: @MattC Added stack trace

Comment: Could you provide your server side configuration file or if you don't have, the lines where you create the host?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Added server config

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with one of the clients in your Clients collection on the server. On one of your previously connected clients when you call their callback method RefreshClients, you are getting an exception thrown. As this isn't caught and handled, it makes it back to the client which called ClientConnect.

Registering a Faulted callback to remove it from your Clients collection is insufficient for two reasons: First, you could hit a race condition where it goes into a faulted state while you are iterating through the Clients collection. Also some failure modes aren't discovered until you attempt to make a call. You need to wrap your callbacks in a try/catch block.

You have some other potential issues, too: If two clients call ClienConnect at almost the same time, you could have clientA's call in a foreach block iterating over Clients when clientB is calls Clients.Add. This will cause the iteration to throw an exception as the underlying collection was modified.